# Problem componentDidMount set state like DidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to use my "componentDidMount" as the "componentDidUpdate". I would like to be able to fill

> this.state.libelle_prerequis

like

> this.setState({libelle_prerequis: this.state.donnees.libelle_prerequis
>   });

donnes = {id: 1, libelle_prerequis: "dde"}

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      donnees: '',
      libelle_prerequis: '',
      error: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevsProp) {
    if (prevsProp.store !== this.props.store) {
      this.setState({
        donnees: this.props.store.libellesprerequis.find((p) => p.id == this.props.libelleprerequis.match.params.id),
      });
      this.setState({ libelle_prerequis: this.state.donnees.libelle_prerequis });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(() => ({
      donnees: this.props.store.libellesprerequis.find((p) => p.id == this.props.libelleprerequis.match.params.id),
    }));
  }

  render() {
    <input
      className="form-control"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Libellé"
      autoFocus
      value={this.state.libelle_prerequis ? this.state.donnees.libelle_prerequis : ''}
      onChange={this.onLibellePrerequisChange}
    />;
  }
```

Comment: What's going wrong?

Comment: I would like to instantiate my variable "libelle_prerequis" using componentDidMount but it does not work i try : this.setState(() => ({ libelle_prerequis: this.state.donnees.libelle_prerequis }))  in componentDidMount But it's empty

Comment: have you tried adding it in the constructor method?

Comment: yes i try make :  this.setState(() => ({ libelle_prerequis: this.state.donnees.libelle_prerequis }))  in my constructor but its empty in the render

Comment: not this.setState... but 
`this.state = {
      donnees: this.props.store.libellesprerequis.find((p) => p.id === this.props.libelleprerequis.match.params.id),
      libelle_prerequis: '',
      error: '',
    };`

Comment: what's the reason why you are assigning props to your state? I think it's better to just use the props value directly so your component will always re-render on any data updates from your parent component or global store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 getDonnees = () => {
  const { store, libelleprerequis } = this.props;
  return store.libellesprerequis.find((p) => p.id == libelleprerequis.match.params.id);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevsProp) {
  if (prevsProp.store !== this.props.store) {
    const donnees = this.getDonnees();
    this.setState({
      donnees,
      libelle_prerequis: donness ? donnees.libelle_prerequis : ''
    });
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  const donnees = this.getDonnees()
  this.setState({
    donnees
  });
}
```

You can also add checks to see if `donnees` is found or not. Assuming `donness` is a constant whose value will not be mutated.

Comment: The reason your code wasn't setting new value of libelle_prerequis was setState is async so, the new value of donness didn't came in effect.

Comment: @hulriche I have updated my answer, it will make your code look cleaner.

Comment: When i refresh my page : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'libelle_prerequis' of undefined
    at EditLibellePrerequisForm.componentDidMount

Comment: you got donness as undefined

Comment: Apply condition to see check if donness is undefined or not and apply default value when encountered @hulriche

Comment: yes I just thought to check the value, I'm going to make a condition in my componentDidMount thank you